# Count number of Login not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to limit the number of Logins to 2 in my Laravel Application. So I did this in my controller, but it is not working for me.

```
 public function authenticated(Request $request,User $user){
        if(Auth::check()){ //check if the user is logged in or not
            $user = Auth::user();

            if ($user->isCouple()) {
                $previous_session = $user->session_id;
                $login = $user->no_of_logins->count() > 2;

                if (($previous_session) && $login )
                {
                 \Session::getHandler()->destroy($previous_session);
                  Auth::user()->no_of_logins--;
                 } }

                 Auth::user()->session_id = \Session::getId();
                 Auth::user()->no_of_logins++;
                 Auth::user()->save();
                 return redirect(route('home'));
                 }  } }
```

In my `user` model, I have a method `iscouple`

```
public function isCouple()
{
    return $this->role=='couple';
}
```

In my `User Table` I have this

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->enum('role', ['subscriber', 'admin', 'basic', 'couple', 'family'])->default('subscriber');
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
        $table->integer('no_of_logins')->default(0);
        $table->string('session_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

## UPDATE

I have updated my controller to  this

```
public function authenticated(Request $request,User $user)
        {
            if(Auth::check())
            { 
                $user = Auth::user();
                if ($user->isCouple()) 
                {
                   $previous_session = $user->session_id;
                   $login = $user->no_of_logins;
                   if ($login > 2){
                        if ($previous_session)
                            {
                            \Session::getHandler()->destroy($previous_session);
                            Auth::user()->no_of_logins--;
                            }
                    }
                   Auth::user()->session_id = \Session::getId();
                   Auth::user()->no_of_logins++;
                   Auth::user()->save();
                   return redirect(route('home'));
                }  
            } 
        }
```

It's not returning error, but I was expecting  `if ($login > 2)` to be checked before logging in. But I tried to login on multiple devices and it kept logging in  and the `no_of_logins` keep increasing. I want to be able to prevent login when `no_of_logins = 2`

Comment: if the field` no_of_logins` is an integer why are you trying to use that attribute on the model as an object? ... and if you are in the `authenticated` method, the user is logged in, "authenticated"

Comment: Oh I am not supposed to use count

Comment: Even when I removed count, it's not working.

Comment: you get an error? what is not working? what controller is that method added to ... context

Comment: The increment works. But I want to limit to 2 device login. 
That's why I use this
 $login = $user->no_of_logins;
if ($login > 2){
                if ($previous_session)
                           {
                            \Session::getHandler()->destroy($previous_session);
                            Auth::user()->no_of_logins--;

                        }
                    }
But the if statement ( if ($login > 2)) is not working

Comment: update the code in your question to what you are currently using and remove the comments

Comment: @lagbox I have updated the code

Comment: What's the problem? You just wrote "It's not working for me". Do you get errors? Explain more or nobody will be able to help you. By the way please format your code it's very ugly and difficult to search for bugs in such unformatted lines!

Comment: Please take a few minutes to format your code. Indent it properly.

Comment: you say "before logging in", the `authenticated` method on LoginController runs "after" they are logged in

Comment: @thmspl have updated my code and formatted it properly.

Comment: this code does not stop you from logging in, all this code does is attempt to destroy a previous session

Comment: @lagbox I don't know what to do, that why I came here. I have made research before coming here. I am new in laravel and I trying to learn. Please if you can explain to me what to do. I will be glad and it will help me to improve

Comment: Why aren't you using `Auth::logout()` to log the user out instead of destroying the session (or whatever this is in your case)?

Comment: @thmspl I just came across this now on youtube and I am learning on how to use it.

Comment: @thmspl Thanks, I have been able to solve it using what you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve the problem. Using 'Auth::logout();` solve it for me.

```
public function authenticated(Request $request,User $user)
    {
        if(Auth::check())
        { 
            $user = Auth::user();
            if ($user->isCouple()) 
                {
                    $login = $user->no_of_logins;
                    if ($login > 2)
                        {
                             Auth::logout();
                        }
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Auth::logout();` instead of your current code:

```
$previous_session = $user->session_id;

if ($previous_session) {
    \Session::getHandler()->destroy($previous_session);
}
```

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication) you can read more about the Laravel Authentication package and it's functionality.